# Copy text from cells based on a different cells answer

Tags: vba, copy, formula

i am trying to create an order form that copies the customers address details that are in cells C8:C13, I have created a drop down in cell G15 that asks if the customers billing address is the same - yes or no, if the answer is yes I want to the data from c8:c13 to be copied into C16:C21

alternatively I could look to hide the rows C16:C21?

I tried initially to right an IF formula however it just returns true or false.

Comment: =IF($G$15="Yes",C8,"") Stick this in C16 and then copy it down to C21. I dont know what you want to do if the drop down is No so atm it is blank?

Answer (score 1):

I think this might fix you problem.

1. Create a ActiveX ComboBox on whatever cell you want (let's stick with the same cell you wanted, so cell G15);
2. Open Visual Basic (***Developer > Visual Basic***);
3. Insert a module (***Insert > Module***)
4. Now lets insert the module code to populate the combobox:

   ```
   Private Sub Workbook_Open()
       With Sheet1.ComboBox1
           ' Clear values
           .Clear
           ' Populate list
           .AddItem "Yes"
           .AddItem "No"
        End With
    End Sub
   ```
5. On your module put this code:

   ```
   Sub copyThis()
       'Defining the variables
       Set adressBill = Range("C8:C13")
       Set destBill = Range("C16:C21")

       'If the combobox is Yes then copy
       If Sheet1.ComboBox1.Value = "Yes" Then
           adressBill.Select
           Selection.Copy
           destBill.Select
           ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Paste        
       End If    
   End Sub
   ```
6. If you want to update the values whenever the combobox value changes just click ***Design Mode*** on the *Developer* tab, and select your combobox and click **View Code** and put this code in it:

   ```
   Private Sub ComboBox1_Change()
       'Calling the function whenever a value changes
       Call copyThis
   End Sub
   ```

Results:
[image: Results]

This method is much easier than a formula (and probably safer aswell), since you can't reference a combobox object (directly) in a formula. Instead, you could use the ***LinkedCell property*** in the ComboBox.